# WPF project with Grids

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have this Windows app:

```
<Window x:Class="PlayTube.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="800" Width="1400">
<Grid Background="#FFD86F6F">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Height="70" Background="#FF9A9A9A">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Height="25" Width="200" Name="SearchTextBox" />
        <Button Grid.Column="2" Height="25" Width="80" Content="Search" Click="Button_Click" />
    </Grid>

    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200" MaxWidth="250" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="300" MaxWidth="350"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid Background="#FFFFFF89">

        </Grid>

        <GridSplitter HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
              VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
              Grid.Column="1" ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext"
              Width="5" Background="#FFBCBCBC" />

        <Grid Background="#FF05BECB" Grid.Column="2">

        </Grid>

        <GridSplitter HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
              VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
              Grid.Column="3" ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext"
              Width="5" Background="#FFBCBCBC"/>

        <Grid Background="#FF4E04A7" Grid.Column="4">
            <MediaElement Stretch="Fill" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

As you can see i have 3 `Grids` and i want to know if it possible the every grid will be managed from a class, because i dont want that all the logic will be in this main Windows class.

Comment: Are you saying that you want the content of each grid to come from another file? Like a user control?

Comment: I am new in the all thing of .net,I try the UserControl but when i create one it's not give me a xaml file for the edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on your project select the Add sub menu and then select user control, you should get this dialog.

[image]

Give the control a name and click ok

build your project and look in the toolbox, you should see right at the top that the new user control you added will be there.

[image]

drag this item in to the content of your grid and it should set everything up for you.

afer doing this my window now looks like

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1" x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <local:UserControl1 HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: I do all of this and when i add `<local:UserControl1 H...` i get this message : `'VideoControl' does not exist in XML namespace 'clr-namespace:application'.` and i add this too : x`mlns:local="clr-namespace:PlayTube"`

Comment: Did you build the application after adding the user control? the designer can be a bit strange with things like that.